# DB transaction is not working in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, transactions

My db transaction having so many insert queries,

```
DB::transaction(function() use ($visaForms, $fields) {
            foreach ($visaForms as $visaForm) {
                $visaForm->save();
                foreach ($fields as $field) {
                    $field->visaForm()->associate($visaForm);
                    $field->save();
                    $field->details()->saveMany($field->getDetails());
                    !empty($field->getOptions()) ? $field->options()->saveMany($field->getOptions()) : NULL;
                    !empty($field->getRules()) ? $field->rules()->attach($field->getRules()) : NULL;
                }
            }
        });
```

When `Integrity constraint violation` throws by `attach()` function, Complete transactions are not rolling back. partial insertion will happening there.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is your database egnine innoDB or MyISAM ? MyISAM knows nothing about transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_engine) if your database engine supports transactions. I usually use transactions this way:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    //Code (DB insertions, ...)
    DB::commit();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    //Handle error
}
```